# Global error handling for a better KeyError treatment

Tags: python

I would like improve the `KeyError` Exception message in order to see the keys that are in the dictionary.

*Example:*
Before: KeyError 'x'
After: KeyError 'y' (keys: ['a', 'b'])

The reason is that I'm constantly losing time to debug what happens and what keys are inside the dict. We have a large buiseness program, so I want to have a global error handler and the Exception can happen at any depth. A simply try except KeyError doesn't do the trick, since I don't have access to that dict anymore.

Is there a way to globaly override the KeyError Exception in order to store and get access to the failed dict that has been used?

Comment: maybe try `dict.get(key, None)`

Comment: @sahasrara62 *Hiding* the error hardly solves the bug.

Comment: @sahasrara62 Please read my request carefully before answering

Comment: @DennyWeinberg it was just a suggestion, not an answer

Comment: try [stackprinter](https://github.com/cknd/stackprinter)

Comment: In case of a KeyError get might help you to get back the faulty dict instead of None - `dict.get(key, dict)` then you don't need try except and you can still see what it was performed on? or maybe only the keys `dict.get(key, dict.keys())`?

Comment: @elonzh nice. It uses sys.excepthook, which is quite interesting. However, I don't get access to my dict yet.

Comment: I don't believe you're able to modify the attributes of built-ins at all in python. A global override for `KeyError` or even `dict`s doesn't sound doable. Using `sys.excepthook` to catch the exception and get the traceback sounds like your best bet to me, but it seems you've said it doesn't suit your needs.

Comment: Thank you guys. I imagine creating a custom dict class that raises a custom KeyError  and using it at some key points in our product. That way I will cover... maybe... 90% of our code, which is already better than now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I used right now, since we can't override the builtins.

```
class LXKeyError(KeyError):
    def __init__(self, item, d):
        self.item = item
        self.d = d

    def __str__(self):
        keys = str(list(self.d.keys()))

        if len(keys) > 1000:  # (13 (max field length in uf) + 4 ("', '")) * 50 (max number of fields we want to print) = 850
            keys = f'{keys[:995]} ...'

        return f'Unknown key in dict: {self.item!r} (keys: {keys})'


class LXDict(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        raise LXKeyError(key, self)
```

Test:

```
orig_d = {'a': 'a', 'b': 'b', '1': '', '2': '', '3': '', '4': '', '5': '', '6': '', '7': '', '8': '', '9': '', '10': '', '11': '', '12': '',
          '13': '', '14': '', '15': '', '16': '', '17': '', '18': '', '19': '', '20': '',
}
d = LXDict(orig_d)
try:
    d['x']
    assert False, f'Should not arrive here'
except KeyError as ex:
    print(ex)
```